# Should this be 5 separate questions?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

This [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/808/why-and-how-would-a-completely-urbanized-city-planet-exist) is made up of 5 separate well worded questions on the topic of a planet-wide city. Addressing them all will make for **very** long answers, and addressing just one per answer will make for answers that cannot be compared by voting. It has been suggested in the comments that the asker repost as separate questions. Should this be enforced by closing this question or are there reasons to keep them together?

---

#### This question has now been deleted and split into separate parts

Comment: Is there a rough guideline for maximum answer length? I agree that this particular question would be better posed as five separate questions, but is there any intrinsic reason that long answers are impossible or unacceptable?

Comment: @CAgrippa there is general guidance somewhere that if an question requires a book to answer it then it is not a good fit for the site, but I've seen nothing more specific so I think it's going to be up to the community to decide on a case by case basis.

Comment: Sometimes a long answer is a good thing. The problem is a question that demands long answers. If there can't be a short answer then the question has a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an advantage to keeping the 5 questions in one, and the disadvantages of excessively long answers and answers that cannot be compared by voting makes me certain that this should be split up. Answers to the individual questions can still cross-reference each other if they wish.

In the meantime the question should be closed to prevent time being wasted on answers that will later have to be split up and rewritten.

---

The day after the post was split up, I've noticed another advantage: The individual questions now show up separately in the unanswered questions list, so the last to be answered is highlighted as still needing an answer. In a combined question once there are a few answers there would be much less reason for people to go in and decide which sub-question still needed an answer. Separating ensures no aspect is overlooked.

Comment: I split them up and cross-referenced them, actually before I saw the meta post.  There's likely to be some duplication between answers on the various posts, but it's no matter.

Comment: @kikjezrous yes I noticed my link was already broken the moment I posted - you beat me to it.

Comment: @kikjezrous I like the separated questions. In addition to the reasons I listed, looking at them now I can see that some have attracted several answers while another has none. I think this works well - in a single question one sub-question being overlooked would not be obvious, but as separate questions the unanswered one will show up in the unanswered questions list and people will know that it is still looking for answers.